# Generate a AR-JWT token

Tags: api, jwt

I'm trying to access an API that accepts JWT tokens. How to generate a JWT token from the credentials (username, password)?

Comment: I understand I mentioned the bmc API. However, generating the JWT token is common for all scenarios, not just specific for this problem alone. I don't see the reason for the negative responses

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out the way.

```
curl -X POST  -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -d "username=username&password=password"  https://<domain>/api/jwt/login  -vvv
```